# Inside Airport transfer, China

Tags: china, airport-transfer, china-eastern

I am traveling to and fro from KIX (Osaka, Japan) to CCU (Kolkata, India) via China Eastern airlines.

The going flight has 3 stops in China, at **DLC (2h 10min, China), YNT (1h, China)** and **KMG (2h 30min, China)** and,

the returning one has 2 stops in China, **KMG (2h 25min, China)** and **NKG (3h 30min, China)**

{All layovers are **"Connect via airport"**}

I heard people saying we need to produce China visa if we have more than 1 stop or 2 stops or something like that. Being a first flier on own, can anyone please help me to clarify will there be any problem in these Chinese airports if I am travelling without any Chinese visa.

I have an Indian Passport.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I meanwhile had some look at the 24 hour TWOV regulation in china which says if the entry point and exit point time difference is less than 24 hr, we don'e need visa. Saying that I am not planning to go out of the transfer zone, I am not clear whether we should take any pass or sticker kind of thing saying that I am eligible for 24 TWOV or is it like just valid through all the airports as the time is less than 24hr for my flight.

Comment: If you plan to get on a domestic flight, you _don't have the option_ of  "not planning to go out of the transit zone". The gate a domestic flight departs from will be outside that zone, so you need to choose between not getting on the flight or leaving the transit zone!

Comment: "Not planning to leave airport for sightseeing" 
*correction*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once travelled from AMS (Amsterdam, the Netherlands) to PNH (Phnom Penh, Cambodia) using KLM and China Southern Airlines with stops in PEK (Beijing, China) and CAN (Guangzhou, China). At PEK I got a visa free transit visum. In CAN this visum would be stamped again and I would be leaving the country. The same in reverse order on the way back.

The wikipedia page [Visa policy of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China) explains the rules about the 24-hour TWOV (transit-without-visa) policy. India is not excluded from this policy. Neither are the airports of your stops. The only thing you have to keep in mind is the duration of 24 hours. Reading your itinerary this should be OK. I don't know about the frequency of flights on the airports you have as stops in case you miss one of the flights. Especially with the 1h stop in YNT.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps. And, Where should the visa free transit form should be collected in the first airport ? Are there any places explicitly present to allot these to us?

Comment: Most up-to-date information: https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/china/708095-china-24-72-144-hour-transit-without-visa-twov-rules-master-thread.html